# AJAX Request returns 'The entity is not a well-formed 'application/json' document. Missing or empty input","code":"400"'

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

As I was trying to create an AJAX request in order to post some users against an external API, I encountered this issue preventing me from doing so. I haven't used JS as much as PHP and I thought this would be a good time to start learning a bit more.

The method I made checks first if the form `contactForm` has been fully completed, while it hasn't, it prevents the js from sending the data and  showing the next form `customerForm`.

If all the data has been properly filled, the js sends the data to the api via AJAX and hides that form to display the next one.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var contactForm = document.getElementById('contactForm');
    var customerForm = document.getElementById('customerForm');

    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(contactForm, function(form) {
      contactForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (contactForm.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        contactForm.classList.add('was-validated');

        if (contactForm.checkValidity() === true) {
            customerForm.style.display = 'block';
            contactForm.style.display = 'none';
            event.preventDefault();
            (function() {
                var contactEmail = document.getElementById('contactEmail').value;
                var contactResellerId = 2;
                var contactName = document.getElementById('contactName').value;
                var contactLastName = document.getElementById('contactLastName').value;
                var contactCompany =  document.getElementById('contactCompany').value;
                var contactRegNum = document.getElementById('contactRegNum').value;

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    withCredentials: true,
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        firstname: contactName,
                        lastname: contactLastName,
                        company: contactCompany,
                        email: contactEmail,
                        reseller_id: contactResellerId,
                        comregnum: contactRegNum
                    }),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Basic '+token,
                    }
                })
                .done(function (response) { alert('Se ha creado el contacto!'); })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(jqXHR); });
            })();
        }
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

Whenever I try to execute this, it returns:

> The entity is not a well-formed 'application/json' document. Missing or empty input","code":"400"

Form values are being correctly fetched into the variables, as `console.log()` proves.

What does the message mean by input? Have I forgotten something?

As always, thank you all for the help, have a nice weekend!

Comment: Print the json being sent and compare it against what the API expects to receive. At a glance it looks like the json should be generating fine, but if a propery is being set as '' or null where the API expects a value, that would be a reasonable response.

Comment: The page you are trying to call has no application/json response or valid json. Or change the backend so it returns a valid json response. Or maybe you could "dataType: 'json'," from your code although this is not a nice solution.

Comment: @Gavin thank you for the quick answer! I have just double checked but it would seem the data is properly fetched and the structure and data type as well

Comment: Hey @JeroendeBeer! thank you for taking your time to answer. Sadly I have no access to the backend since the API is not from our creation, and I already have data: json. Could this be because I lack ssl certificate?

Comment: If you console.log the entire xhr in the fail callback it might have the raw returned body.

Comment: @Gavin Just tried what you suggested, it shows the data fetched from the form and the same error code  `The entity is not a well-formed 'application/json' document. Missing or empty input`

Comment: I don't know if this can play as a clue, but I have the same application on php/cURL and there, whenever I disable cURL options `SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `SSL_VERIFYPEER`, the data is correctly uploaded to the API. That's why I tried JS instead, not wanting to make an insecure function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asnwer to this one was actually quite easy: My AJAX request was indeed not well formed for it lacked some attributes. This is how it should have been:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',      <------- THIS
    crossDomain: true,
    withCredentials: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        firstname: contactName,
        lastname: contactLastName,
        company: contactCompany,
        email: contactEmail,
        reseller_id: contactResellerId,
        comregnum: contactRegNum
    }),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',   <------ THIS
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token,
    }
});
```